# Is there a way to emulate Chrome's now dead App Launcher?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I loved Chrome's app launcher, I had it pinned on my taskbar (Windows) next to the start button. Since the latest update to Chrome all it does is open Chrome at **chrome://apps**, which I suppose is OK functionally but it really isn't as nice as the dedicated launcher.

Could I tell **chrome://apps** to open in a new window like you can when you add a website to the desktop (Menu => More tools => Add to desktop)?